# Store session data in Controller when SessionStateBehavior is ReadOnly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, devexpress-mvc

In an ASP.Net MVC page I have a few partial views (DevExpress controls) that I need to load in parallel. For this to happen I need the Session to be ReadOnly, because I need the actions in controller to be called async. 
My problem is that until now (when Session wasn't ReadOnly) I was able to store some info in Session, I have used in controller properties like:

```
private string myVarToKeepForThisSession
    {
        get
        {
            if (Session["myVar"] == null)
            {
                Session["myVar"] = "";
            }
            return (string)Session["myVar"];
        }
        set
        {
            if (Session != null)
            {
                Session["myVar"] = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

And now this of course it doesn't work any more. I can assign a value to  myVarToKeepForThisSession but on the next ajax call it will be empty. So I need a way to keep this functionality for Session (or some alternative solution for actions to be called async but also to be able to store a couple of strings).

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Comment: Are the values specific to a user or will the be the same for all users? Trying to see if you can use static properties.

Comment: Yes they are (I can't use static properties), actually they are specific to session. There are some values that a user can select (from a dropdown or I store the id of a selected row in a datagrid) and based on that when he does another action (like click a button or do another selection in a new enabled dropdown) then some "things happen" (specific data is loaded in a partial view based on that combination of actions done by the user).